How should I use Llama-3 properly?
I downloaded the Meta-Llama-3-70B-Instruct model using the download.sh and the url provided by Meta email, and this is all the files in the folder.
enter image description here
And when I tried to use this model using the following code, this error occurs: OSError: Meta-Llama-3-70B-Instruct does not appear to have a file named config.json. How can I fix this error?
Code:
import transformers
import torch
model_id = "Meta-Llama-3-8B-Instruct"
pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model_id,
    model_kwargs={
        "torch_dtype": torch.bfloat16
    },
    device_map="auto"
)
clinical_notes_path = 'clinical notes_20/note1.txt'
with open(clinical_notes_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    clinical_notes = file.read()
examples = [
    ("Patient complains of severe headache and dizziness.", "Entities: headache, dizziness"),
    ("Examination shows elevated blood pressure and a rash on the lower limb.", "Entities: elevated blood pressure, rash"),
    ("Prescribed medications include Ibuprofen and Amoxicillin.", "Entities: Ibuprofen, Amoxicillin")
]
example_text = "\n".join([f"Text: {text}\nEntities: {entities}" for text, entities in examples])
clinical_notes_path = 'clinical notes_20/note1.txt'
with open(clinical_notes_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    clinical_notes = file.read()

prompt = (
    example_text + "\n\n"
    "New clinical notes:\n" + clinical_notes + "\n"
    # "As an experienced doctor, please identify and list all medical entities in the given clinical notes:"
    "Here are all medical entities appeared in the given clinical notes: "
)

output = pipeline(prompt, max_length=1024,max_new_tokens=512)
generated_text = output[0]['generated_text']
response_start = generated_text.find("New clinical notes:") + len("New clinical notes:")
response = generated_text[response_start:].strip()
print(response)

My guess is that the model files download using download.sh and url from Meta is not the same with the model download from the huggingface? But I don't know how to fix this problem...
